# 365 OOB Approval Workflow - Can I populate with a name from a column or restrict to certain users only?

Tags: approval-process, office-365, out-of-the-box

When we upload a document we populate file attributes with Approver names (this is a hang on from WSS3.0 custom workflows)

Not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I like the ease of the OOB workflows in 365, but want to know if when I create a workflow using the Approval template, I can force the Approver fields to look at the document columns, or limit the users in say the last field as I want to limit the final approver to managers for example?

[image: screenshot]